# Excel match two columns and output third

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

[image]

I would like a formula that iterates over the first and second column and returns the third column if

Column 1 = "a" AND
Column 2 = "d"

the formula should return the value in the third column of the corresponding row, in this case
it would be 3.  otherwise, it should output 0.

Comment: So only the target cell in the first row would return `bo`, and all the others would return 0?

Comment: No.  I would like a formula that returns "bo" if column1 and column2 are matched, and returns "0" otherwise

Comment: @Matt So wait, you want to hard code the result to "bo" or is it supposed to be "bo" because thats whats in column 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the formula:

```
=IF(MATCH("foo",A1:A4,0)=MATCH("bar",B1:B4,0),INDEX(C1:C4,MATCH("bar",B1:B4,0)),0)
```

of course you can change the `"foo"` and `"bar"` text within the formula to use another cell reference.  Anyways, this should get you started at least.

**Edit:**

If `"bar"` is only found once in column `B` Then you can use

```
=IF(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("bar",B1:B4,0))="foo",INDEX(C1:C4,MATCH("bar",B1:B4,0)),0)
```

One last thing, for both cases, if `"bar"` is never found in column B it will return `#N/A` if you want to change that you can wrap the whole thing in an `IFERROR()` statement and return your 0 .

Comment: this is what i am looking for.  however, if i have multiple matches in the first column, it does not work.  I tried to change the match mode to 1, but this gives odd behavior.

Comment: @Matt multiple matches like you have "foo" and "bar" together more than once?

Comment: No, they only appear together once, but there are many "foo" in column 1

Comment: @Matt can there be more than one "bar" in column 2?

Answer (score 0):

is that what you need ?

`=IF(AND(A1="foo",B1="boo"),"boo",0)`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for something like this, assuming column 1 is A1 and column 2 is B1:

```
=IF(AND(A1="foo",B1="bar"),"bo",0)
```

If you have multiple values that you need column 3 to be you can do an embedded if statement like for your second row:

```
=IF(AND(A1="foo",B1="bar"),"bo",IF(AND(A1="fui",B1 = "bas"),"bis",0))
```

Basically where you would have 0, you write the next if statement and it will run through, until it hits true or defaults to 0.

Comment: i need to apply this to a range though

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Excel has this feature. 
If you are looking up numbers, there is a work around though:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,"a",$B$1:$B$4,"d") = 1, SUMIFS($C$1:$C$4,$A$1:$A$4,"a",$B$1:$B$4,"d"), "ERR")
```

This will yield the number if there is exactly one match, and `"ERR"` if there are none or many matches. If you try to use it to look up text, it will return 0.