# Excel: match two columns and output third ... AND... there are multiple instances in each column

Tags: excel

Working off a previous post:
[Excel match two columns and output third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839932/excel-match-two-columns-and-output-third)

I have values in column A that are not unique and values in column B that are not unique, but together column A and B produce unique combinations:

```
     A     B     C
1   Red   Car   Result#1

2   Blue  Boat  Result #2 

3   Red   Boat  Result #3

4   Green Car   Result #4
```

Let's say I want to find a match where Column A = Red and Column B = Boat which should return the corresponding value in Column C which should be Result #3.

Using the previous post's solution:

`=IF(MATCH("Red",A1:A4,0)=MATCH("Boat",B1:B4,0),INDEX(C1:C4,MATCH("Boat",B1:B4,0)),0)`

This would actually return value the first match for Boat in column B which would be result#2 rather than the intended result#3 where the match was true.

Any ideas on how to modify or write a function that would specify to retrieve information relative to specifically where the match was true (without using VBA)?

I've thought of a possible work around by creating another column that combines Col A and B to make a unique identifier but I was hoping to avoid that.

Thanks! Really appreciate it and sorry about the table formatting. I'm still very new at this.

Comment: I'm gonna have to ask if you could rephrase what you are asking. It would appear that step one of your question was answered. Combining inputs from Column A and B in C based on certain conditions (Such as red and car). What are you asking here?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a two column match using the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to force anything that does not match into an error and ignore the errors.

[image: INDEX AGGREGATE with two column MATCH]

The formula in E6 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C$99,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$99)/((A$1:A$99="red")*(B$1:B$99="boat")), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

You are actually using the [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) sub-function of the AGGREGATE function so you can get the second, third, etc. successive matches by increasing the *k* paramter. I done this above by using `ROW(1:1)` which equals 1 but will increase to 2, 3, etc as the formula is filled down.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a third column is the most efficient solution. However if you absolutely have to avoid it, you could use a complicated formula like this:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$6,MATCH(A11,$A$1:$A$6,0) + MATCH(B11,OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(A11,$A$1:$A$6,0)-1,1,COUNTA($A$1:$A$6)-MATCH(A11,$A$1:$A$6,0),1),0)-1)
```

But the condition is that the lookup table is sorted for both column 1 and 2.