# Excel 2013 VLOOKUP() based on multiple criteria, retrieving multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue that can (I believe) be solved by just excel, and may won't require VBA (I could be wrong). I believe it can be solved by nested functions but the formula I've tried has not worked.

Here's my data:

```
 Name               Report #          Name
Mark Doe            ReportXXX       Mark Doe
Connie Doe          ReportYYY       Connie Doe
Debbie Doe          REPORTYYY       Debbie Doe  
Valerie Doe         FSMVALTR1       Valerie Doe
Jeff Doe            FSMVALTR1       Jeff Doe
Andy Doe            RAZXYBCA1       Andy Doe    
Ryan Doe            RAZXYBCA1       Ryan Doe    
Andy Doe            RAZ111111       Jill Doe    
Ryan Doe            RAZ222112       Amanda Doe
```

This list goes on for about ~4000 rows in the first NAME and REPORT # columns. In the second NAME column I have ~160 rows.

The second name column identifies all the users who actually use the report, with no duplicates. The two name and report # columns have many duplicates, since users have access to multiple reports, and many of them are the same report used for different purposes. Since the second NAME column has so few rows, the names don't match up all the way through, which can be observed near the bottom of both the NAME columns.

What I need to do is have a `VLOOKUP` that identifies the name in both of the columns and then returns the report number that each individual has access to across rows (horizontally), not down the columns. It also needs to I.D. numerous reports since individuals have access to anywhere from 1-15 reports, starting at the second and so on after the previous has been extracted.

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
Name          Report #      Name       ex column  ex column  ex column
Mark Doe      ReportXXX    Mark Doe    ReportXXX  ReportAAA   ReportB
```

I didn't list the other reports "Mark Doe" has access to and these would be somewhere down the long list of ~4000, along with his name repeated multiple times in the first NAME column, but the second "unique" name column would be where it is returning the reports to, across rows.

Comment: You can use array formula, so index(a1:c10,if((a1:a10="xyx")*(c1:c10="abc"),row(a1:a10)),1)   have a look at array formula

Comment: See [match two columns and output third … AND… there are multiple instances in each column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979340/excel-match-two-columns-and-output-third-and-there-are-multiple-instance/31980952#31980952).

Comment: I see that, except in this case you have to specify the "Name" and "Report #" to return the value. This won't work because I have 167 names and cannot do an iteration of this formula that many times. How can it be name "agnostic" and just return the value of the report if it matches the two name columns?

Comment: @Jeeped In that example he specifies "red" "boat", I can't specify that for each report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a method that uses additional three columns and it worked for me.
I used the data you provided above.

Add three columns to the left.

- in A2 enter `=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D2,D2,$E$2:$E2,E2)`.
- in B2 enter `=SUMIFS($A$2:$A2,$A$2:$A2,1,$D$2:D2,D2)`.
- in C2 enter `=D2&B2`.

Now copy those cells to all your 4000 rows.

Now next to the second name column add column headers numbered from 1 to as many reports you think can be the max one user can have (you said 15).

Now enter this `vlookup` in F2 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F2&G$1, your table array starting from column C as absolute/fixed ,3,FALSE),"")` in my case it was `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F2&G$1,$C$2:$E$11,3,FALSE),"")`.

Copy the formula accross all columns with number headers and down all rows that have names in second name column (160).

[your sheet shuld look something like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa06u.jpg)

All the best let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I think this is actually working - going to implement and validate. Could you explain to me how this works exactly?

Comment: I'm very interested in understanding the mechanics..think I know, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: so this woks as follows; column A counts how many times this user used that particular report from beginning of table up to that point. column B gives you a count of the number unique report the user is up to at that point. then by joining the user name and number report hes up to we can ID for `Vlookup` what to search for. hope i'v been clear to understand. glad to help if needed

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored the option of using a Pivot Table?

The output would look like this:

[image]

With the Pivot Table setup like this:

[image]

This method would make for a cleaner view, as your current method looks to repeat ~4,000 times (once for each report & name combo).  Hopefully this works for what you need.

Comment: This won't work, it won't be an exact match between the two name columns, plus there are other criteria to the right that are about ~160 rows too, need to condense the 4000.