# Excel - Trying to get a "frequency" number for an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set with report numbers, users, and managers that I'm trying to gather some info on.

I want to get the top 25 most used and bottom 25 least used report NUMBERS

Here's how the data looks:

```
UserName     Manager           Report1    Report2  Report3...560 columns

Luke         Luke's MGR        ReportA    ReportB   ReportC
David        David's MGR       ReportB    ReportC   ReportD
Alan         Alan's MGR        ReportC    ReportG   ReportF
.                 .               .          .         .
.                 .               .          .         .
167 rows
```

This data goes on for 167 rows and ~560 columns.

I also have a set of data that looks like this:

```
Report      Username    Additional Columns
ReportA      Luke
ReportB      Tom
ReportC      Alan
ReportB      Alan
ReportF      Tom
ReportB      Luke
```

Both of these contain the same information. The first dataset has the reports listed vertically, so the row length is only as long as the unique amount of actual users (i.e. 1 user - no duplicates)

The second dataset is much longer (~4200 rows) because there are multiple duplicates of reports as well as users, and it doesn't distinguish between each individuals manager which is a problem.

What I want is to get the top 25 most used and bottom 25 least used reports from this list. I have created a pivot to get the most/least used reports but I can't pull the name/manager name with it. I prefer to work with the first data set, but it seems it may be more difficult to work with this one.

Ideally my output would look like so:

```
Report#       MNGR1         MNGR2  Username1  Username2    Username3
ReportA      Bridgett        Luke     Zach        Mitch       Calli
.              MNGR2         MNGR3
.              MNGR4         MNGR5
ReportZ        Ron           Andy          .           .            .
```

The bottom 25 are only used by one person each and the top 25 can be used by as many as 38 individuals.

It may not be possible to do the manager portion, but if I could at least get the usernames horizontally by the top/bottom 25 most used reports that would be great. I could do this manually, but it would be very tedious.

[This is how I got to the first table of data I posted FROM the second set.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894988/excel-2013-vlookup-based-on-multiple-criteria-retrieving-multiple-rows)

Comment: What have you tried and where have you run into trouble? How are you planning to handle the issue where the same report is generated by multiple user/manager pairs?  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you give an example of the 2nd set of data you describe? The one that "goes vertically down", I am having trouble picturing it. Is it just one column? Two?

Comment: Updated my question...

Comment: If you want to use the first set of data then I'd [unpivot (flatten) the data](http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel) first and then summarize it again with a new pivot table to whatever I want. Ideally, I'd have a DB server to connect to and do all the work for me.

Comment: @Ralph That won't work. Data came as text file. The owner(s) (access admins) gave me this in excel and told me to do this. I didn't pivot to get in this manner either. Did countif, sumif, and another functions then did a VLOOKUP so I could get multiple report #'s per one unique individual without it just returning the first report in the column. I added an update at the bottom of my post for reference on how I got table 1