# Excel lookup multiple values with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I have two tables that I need to compare return a true or false value, the challenge is the user ID appears multiple times in both tables which means my VLOOKUP gets stuck at the first value.

**Table 1 relates to Messages sent to users**

[image]

**Table 2 relates to Orders made by users**

[image]

I want to compare the two tables and see if a user has placed an order within 14 days of being sent each message.

I have tried using a Pivot for table 2 with UserID across the top and date down the left, then using Vlookup and Hlookup to return a value for the exact date but I can never get past looking at an exact date or the first value rather than all values.

Comment: See [Excel: match two columns and output third … AND… there are multiple instances in each column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979340/excel-match-two-columns-and-output-third-and-there-are-multiple-instance/31980952#31980952).

Comment: Since you are just wanting to say "Yes" or "No" that a record exists based on multiple criteria, I think `=COUNTIFS()` is the way to go. `COUNTIFS()` lets you make a count of rows that match multiple conditions.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill your suggestion triggered a solution that has worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped too, turns out that solution was even better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just wanting to say "Yes" or "No" that a record exists based on multiple criteria, I think =COUNTIFS() is the way to go. COUNTIFS() lets you make a count of rows that match multiple conditions. – JNevill Mar 15 '16 at 17:33