# Multiple IF statements to determine a match and assign value

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am running a small study that basically needs to match suitable people into pairs and assign them a pair number, so each can be assigned into group A or B.
They basically need to be from the same Medical Clinic, same gender, and either below 80, or 80+ years of age.

I'm not sure if this is even possible with excel, but basically I have a sheet with a form that you enter the new participants information. I need a formula that basically checks these 3 criteria against previous entries to find someone who matches on all 3, then assign the same pair number. If it can't find a suitable match, it needs to assign a new pair number.

[image: Here is a sample data set]

In the above sample data set, I want I3 to realise that C3, D3 and E3 all match C2, D2 and E2, then put a 1 in I3.

Then for I4, it would assign a 2 as it doesn't match any entries above it. Same for I5. Then I6 would realise the match in I4 and put a 2.

Not sure if this makes sense. Also there can't be more than 2 of each pair #, but I can deal with that after I am able to get the numbers generating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [match two columns and output third … AND… there are multiple instances in each column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979340/excel-match-two-columns-and-output-third-and-there-are-multiple-instance/31980952#31980952).

Comment: In the image D3 is different from D2

Comment: @Jeeped If I am following that thread correctly, it is relying on column C to determine the output, whereas my output has to be dynamic, assigning a new number if no match is found, or assigning the same number as a match (assuming that number hasn't already been matched)

Comment: @pcofre Ages don't need to match exactly, just be in the same range. Under 80 or 80+

Comment: ... and that is why I only pointed to it as a possible solution. If I had voted to close this as a true duplicate then your question would no longer be open for responses. The key (as demonstrated in that linked answer) is to use the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to build your multiple column criteria. AGGREGATE also lends itself to returning subsequent matches so you do not have more than a single returned match for each pairing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sup>This response expands on your original requirements by returning the actual **PT ID** numbers of the matched pairs as well as a unique 'paired group' identifier.</sup>
>   <sub>The original criteria age brackets (e.g. 70-80, 81+) are used and no matched pair is used more than once.</sub>

If you already have a match from further up the data then you will want to return the paired PT ID. A simple [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair can do that. If a match has not already been made then the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) can pass processing over to a nested [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) that uses the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) rather then MATCH to return the appropriate row number.

AGGREGATE is used with its [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) sub-function. This allows the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) to increment to the second, third, etc. pairing by examining the matches³ made previously.

With expanded sample data the formula in I2:K2 are,

```
'formula for I2
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B1, MATCH(B2, I$1:I1, 0)),
                 INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(B$1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/
               ((B:B<>B2)*(C:C=C2)*(E:E=E2)*IF(D2>80, D:D>80, (D:D>=70)*(D:D<=80))),
                 COUNTIFS(C$1:C1, C2, E$1:E1, E2, D$1:D1, IF(D2>80, ">80", ">=70"), D$1:D1, IF(D2>80, ">80", "<=80"))+1))), 
         "NO MATCH")
'formula for J2
=IFERROR(INDEX(J$1:J1, MATCH(I2, B$1:B1, 0)), MAX(J$1:J1)+1)
'formula for K2 (volatile and random - see footnote ⁴)
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(K$1:K1, MATCH(J2, J$1:J1, 0))="A", "B", "A"), IF(ISNUMBER(I2), CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65, 66)), ""))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: Blairgowrie]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

² <sub>While AGGREGATE-based formulas are entered as conventional formulas (i.e. without CSE), AGGREGATE does apply cyclic array-style processing. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array processing chews up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

³ <sub>Your original narrative stated *'... either between 70 and 80 or above 80 years of age.'* while your subsequent comment stated *'Under 80 or 80+'*. These are not the same thing. I've used the former original description since you never edited the question for clarification.</sub>

⁴ <sub>The formula destined for K2 is volatile and uses the [RANDBETWEEN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Once you are happy with the results, use *Copy, Paste Special, Values* to revert the formula to its underlying values. Leaving the formula intact with RANDBETWEEN means the values could change with any change throughout the workbook. Only the initial A/B value for each matched pair is random; the match in the pair will always be the A or B counterpart.</sub>

Comment: Not entirely sure what I've copied wrong, but I am getting different results.
I copied your extended data set (essentially), and input these formulas.
[See this example](http://i.imgur.com/TQQAEu8.png) of what results I'm getting. I2 matches I3, but I3 doesn't match I2, but instead matches I7, and I7 matches I9, which matches nothing.

Comment: Have a look at my [sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Multiple%20IF%20statements%20to%20determine%20a%20match%20and%20assign%20value.xlsx) to see if it makes sense.

Comment: It looks like you used `L$1:L1` instead of `I$1:I1`.

Comment: Thanks for this, extremely helpful solution and well formatted guide

Answer (score 2):

If you can change column D to Age group, (71-80, 81-90 etc.) the following formula would do what you want as a first step (more than 2 people grouped together).  Paste the following formula in I3 and hit cntrl+shift+enter as it is a array formula. Copy it down to other cells below.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F$1:F2,MATCH(C3&D3&E3,C$1:C2&D$1:D2&E$1:E2,0)),MAX(F$2:F2)+1)
```

This matches a combination of strings in columns C, D and E in the current row to array of string combination in previous rows and assigns the same Pair number, if there is no match it gets the next new number.

Try this modified formula (array formula) to not put more than two entries in a group.  I have created another column G which is G2 = C2&D2&E2

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G$1:G2,G3)<2,IFERROR(INDEX(F$1:F2,MATCH(C3&D3&E3,C$1:C2&D$1:D2&E$1:E2,0)),MAX(F$2:F2)+1),MAX(F$2:F2)+1)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! 
Any thoughts on how I can limit matches to 2 gives a new number using this formula?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create a new column (J) that concatenates the 3 values you are comparing, you can do this with a formula like this:

```
=C2&IF(D2>80,"YES","NO")&D3
```

The you can fill I2 with a formula that checks is the concatenated value repeats in the data set with a fomula like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($J$2:$J$6,J2)>1
```