# Excel get value of cell in a column based on values of other cells in it's row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is the simplest way to get the value of a cell in a column if the other cells in it's row contains specific values?

I mean without using array formula or adding additional columns to create combined values. Array formula may confuse my students at the moment. I could be wrong but I feel there must be a formula for this. Something like `=GetValue(FromColumn,Condition1Range,Condition1,Condition2Range,Condition2)`

Much like Countifs() but instead of counting, I want to get that value instead.

Example,

[image]

I want to get the date of a row who's year is 2015, week is 1, and day is 5.

Comment: This sounds like a [multi-criteria Index/Match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/). ...except that's an array formula, which you don't need. Perhaps this would be a nice time to introduce them to Array Formulas?

Comment: Yes part of my plan but I wanted to introduce the most basic solution first if there are any. I really thought this would have been a part of excel simple formulas already :s

Comment: You should be able to build something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979340/excel-match-two-columns-and-output-third-and-there-are-multiple-instance/31980952#31980952

Comment: Is a given set of match criteria unique? FTR, any conceivable, clean "non-array" attempt here will do "array" operations under the covers. There are only a couple ways I see you possibly getting a formula that is simple enough so as not to be far more confusing to students than an array formula. 1) with an extra constraint such as "A given match criteria only exists in the table with one date"  2) if you can find a way with SUMPRODUCT. I have #1 mocked up in Excel.